# Streaming video in android from python server

Tags: android, python

I want to upload a video from android to server and have to stream video like youtube.

I have uploaded video from android successfully. But not able to stream video in client

Comment: You have to search on that. Please mention what you done so far.

Comment: @Prabhu first you need video URL for play in your mobile then you can use ExoPlayer or VideoView based on requirement

Comment: what exactly is a problem? ` But not able to stream video in client` how have you tried to do it?

Comment: i have video data in mongodb dabase and that data should stream in android client like youtube